# svnlook changed -t "$rev" "$repos" not getting executed

Tags: perl, batch-file, svn, visualsvn-server, post-commit-hook

As in title I am calling from my post-commit hook script written in perl which has command

```
$msg = `$svnlook changed -t "$rev" "$repos"`;
```

which should execute and than I should send `$msg` to my service. But when I run

```
if ( length($msg) == 0 )
{
    print STDERR "msg length is 0";
    exit(1);
}
```

I get this error message on console, so why is this `svnlook` command not being executed?

I am using windows 7 and VisualSVN server.

On other note, I had other theory to run this command in hook itself like

```
@echo off
set repos=%1
set rev=%2
set changes=svnlook changed %repos% -r %rev% 
C:\Perl64\bin\perl C:\repositories\myproject\hooks\myhook.pl %1 %2 changes
```

but I don't know how to pass this `changes` parameter, so if this could work, it could answer as well.

How to pass parameter from batch to perl script?

Comment: I'm confused why do you need to pass *changes* if you are already performing the *svnlook* command inside of your Perl script? It seems like all you need to pass to your script is the revision# and the repository path.

Comment: You should also note that there are two forms of svnlook, one that accepts a transaction number and one that accepts a revision number. You seem to be using both here for some reason.

Comment: there is a line in middle of question post, first part is where I am trying to execute command in perl script and it is not being executed
in second part I was trying to execute command in batch and then pass result to my script
and neither is working

Comment: where am I using different svnlooks?

Comment: well your first example is probably just a mistake then, you are passing a revision number using `-t` flag which accepts a transaction number. The command should be `\`$svnlook changed -r "$rev" "$repos"\``; You also never explained what you mean by doesn't work? Do you get output you don't expect? Do you get no output? Do you get an error message?

Comment: oh yes, its a stupid typo, because I was doing some copy paste. thats it man
if you want, write a post and I will mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

running svnlook changed help display the list of valid options to `svnlook changed` and their expected format:

```
$ svnlook help changed
changed: usage: svnlook changed REPOS_PATH

Print the paths that were changed.

Valid options:
  -r [--revision] ARG      : specify revision number ARG
  -t [--transaction] ARG   : specify transaction name ARG
  --copy-info              : show details for copies
```

Normally you would specify either a transaction number with `-t` or a revision number with `-r`. You appear to be passing a revision number with `-t` which will lead to unexpected results: either no results or results that are unrelated to the revision you wish to example.

I believe the correct usage in your case would be:

```
my $msg = `$svnlook changed -r "$rev" "$repos"`;
```

The above command is going to give you one long string that is delimited by newlines. You can get this is a more manageable array format by using the same command in list context:

```
my @changes = `$svnlook changed -r "$rev" "$repos"`;
```

additionally these lines will all have trailing newlines, you can eliminate them using the [`chomp()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) built-in:

```
my @changes; 
chomp(@changes = `$svnlook changed -r "$rev" "$repos"`);
```

Alternatively, you could look at [`SVN::SVNLook`](https://metacpan.org/pod/SVN::SVNLook) which a Perl wrapper around the `svnlook` command.

Comment: is there some fast way to turn this output from array to json, I am not very familliar with perl?

Comment: what would you expect the key to be for the json? The name of the file that was altered? If so you could create a hash reference using `{ filename => \@changes }` and pass that to [`JSON`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON#PERL---JSON) module's [`to_json`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON#to_json) function.